# Recoger los meses en HTML y PHP desde un select

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando desarrollar una función para poder recoger los meses en **HTML** y **PHP** desde un `select`. De momento, lo que tengo es:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php

 $mesos = [ "gener" => "31", "febrer" => "28 dies, si és any de traspàs 29",
 "març" => "31", "abril" => "30", "maig" => "31", "juny" => "30",
 "juliol" => "31", "agost" => "31", "septembre" => "30",
 "octubre" => "31", "novembre" => "30", "desembre" => "31",  ];
 //Sino se clica el boton submit entonces...
 if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  ?>
  <!--Aquí he de crear la funcion que recoja el mes y mediante el select lo selecciones y te printee el mes con los años que tiene-->
  <form method="post" action="ex05-4.php">
   <p>Escull el mes :</p>
   <select name="mes">
    <!--Aquí he de implementar el select bien pero no se como -->
   </select> <p />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ves">
  </form>
  <?php
 //Si se envia bien el formulario entonces 
 } else {
  $mesos = $_POST['mesos'];
 }
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow, las preguntas deben contener una descripción del problema en lugar de solo codigo para tener una mejor recepción entre la comunidad, te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por el sitio para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio

Comment: Okay normlamente dejo una descripción del problema pero en esta vez se me pasó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pues si he entendido bien ahora...

**INDEX.PHP**

```
    <?php 
//Esta funcion añade los options en el select recibiendo el array de los meses
function afegirOption($nomMesos){
    foreach($nomMesos as $nom){ 
        echo "<option name='mes' value='".$nom."'>".$nom."</option>";
    }
}
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    $nomMesos = [1=>"Gener", 2=>"Febrer", 3=>"Març", 4=>"Abril", 5=>"Maig", 6=>"Juny", 7=>"Juliol", 8=>"Agost", 9=>"Septembre", 10=>"Octubre", 11=>"Novembre", 12=>"Desembre"];



    //Sino se clica el boton submit entonces...
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        ?>
        <!--Aquí he de crear la funcion que recoja el mes y mediante el select lo selecciones y te printee el mes con los años que tiene-->
        <form method="post" action="ex05-4.php">
            <p>Escull el mes :</p>
            <select name="mes">
                <!-- llamamos a la función y le enviamos el array -->
                <?php afegirOption($nomMesos); ?>
                <!--Aquí he de implementar el select bien pero no se como -->
            </select> <p />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ves">
        </form>
        <?php
    //Si se envia bien el formulario entonces   
    } else {
        $mesos = $_POST['mesos'];
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**ex05-4.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<?php calcularData() ?>

</body>
</html>

<?php
function calcularData(){
    $nomMesos = [1=>"Gener", 2=>"Febrer", 3=>"Març", 4=>"Abril", 5=>"Maig", 6=>"Juny", 7=>"Juliol", 8=>"Agost", 
                                9=>"Septembre", 10=>"Octubre", 11=>"Novembre", 12=>"Desembre"];
    $any = date("Y");
    $calcularData = $any."-".array_search($_POST["mes"], $nomMesos)."-01";
    echo "El mes ".$_POST["mes"]." te ".date('t',strtotime($calcularData)). " dies."; 
}
?>
```

Hay varias maneras, pero creo que la más sencilla es esta, además de éste modo, no tienes que calcular traspàs o no... ya que lo hace de manera automática. La variable $mesos no la he usado para nada, pero puedes adaptarla a la de $nomMesos para tu ejercicio.

**EDITO:** Añado funciones en php, recuerda que las funciones pueden estar dentro de los tags html o fuera de ellos, dependiendo lo que quieras hacer, en este caso, te los he dejado fuera.
Ahora si espero haberte ayudado!

**Opción, todo en un solo archivo:**

```
<?php 
    $nomMesos = [1=>"Gener", 2=>"Febrer", 3=>"Març", 4=>"Abril", 5=>"Maig", 6=>"Juny", 7=>"Juliol", 8=>"Agost", 
                                9=>"Septembre", 10=>"Octubre", 11=>"Novembre", 12=>"Desembre"];
    //Esta funcion añade los options en el select recibiendo el array de los meses
    function afegirOption($nomMesos){
        foreach($nomMesos as $nom){ 
            echo "<option name='mes' value='".$nom."'>".$nom."</option>";
        }
    }
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <!--Aquí he de crear la funcion que recoja el mes y mediante el select lo selecciones y te printee el mes con los años que tiene-->
        <form method="post" action="">
            <p>Escull el mes :</p>
            <select name="mes">
                <!-- llamamos a la función y le enviamos el array -->
                <?php afegirOption($nomMesos); ?>
                <!--Aquí he de implementar el select bien pero no se como -->
            </select> <p />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ves">
        </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        calcularData();
    }


    function calcularData(){
        $nomMesos = [1=>"Gener", 2=>"Febrer", 3=>"Març", 4=>"Abril", 5=>"Maig", 6=>"Juny", 7=>"Juliol", 8=>"Agost", 
                                9=>"Septembre", 10=>"Octubre", 11=>"Novembre", 12=>"Desembre"];
        $any = date("Y");
        $calcularData = $any."-".array_search($_POST["mes"], $nomMesos)."-01";
        echo "El mes ".$_POST["mes"]." te ".date('t',strtotime($calcularData)). " dies.";
    }
?>
```

Si tienes cualquier duda del razonamiento del ejercicio, puedes preguntarme y puedo explicarte paso a paso del porqué de todo el código, no dudes en escribir!

**Opcional**
Para no inicializar $nomMesos  dos veces, arriba puedes poner:

```
global $nomMesos;
    $nomMesos = [1=>"Gener", 2=>"Febrer", 3=>"Març", 4=>"Abril", 5=>"Maig", 6=>"Juny", 7=>"Juliol", 8=>"Agost", 
                                9=>"Septembre", 10=>"Octubre", 11=>"Novembre", 12=>"Desembre"];
```

y luego justo debajo de `function calcularData(){` añades `global $nomMesos;` y así no tienes que volver a añadir $nomMesos = [****].

Comment: Osea he de escoger el mes mediante combo box (osea un select que me diga por ejemplo gener, clique en ese checkbox y me salga un mensaje diciendo **el mes es enero y tiene 31 días** .Esa tendria que ser la respuesta en concreto.

Comment: @Guillem te pido revises [answer] y solo dejes una respuesta, no esta bbien visto publicar de un mismo usuario tantas respuestas a la misma pregunta, dale editar a alguna de las 2 añade lo que haga falta y elimina la otra

Comment: @shadow disculpa, pensé que no podía comentar, ya que siempre me aparece un aviso de falta de puntos, por otro lado, pensé que estaba editando el post original. Ya está solucionado, Gracias!

Comment: @Guillem antes de responder una pregunta es recomendable esperar a que tenga el formato minimo requerido

Comment: Guillem me parece correcto tu código muchas gracias hace lo que quiero lo único que el procedimiento me faltaría hacerlo con una función pero el resto es eso.

Comment: @InfoTipsconJavitoBCN puedes coger la parte de código que necesites en función y subirla añadiendo el function nomFuncio(){}, no sé qué parte necesitas que sea una función

Comment: @Guillem Osea la matriz y la función han de estar fuera del código HTML.

Comment: en el index.php, como de todos modos has de poner las etiquetas <?php ?> para ejecutar la función, te va a resultar lo mismo hacerlo como función que introduciendo directamente la parte que quieres hacer, si según el texto comentado, necesitas la inserción de opciones como funcion, sería así: <?php function crearOpcion($nomMesos){foreach($nomMesos as $nom){ 
      echo "<option name='mes' value='".$nom."'>".$nom."</option>";
     }} y al llamarlo, necesitas pasarle el array <?php crearOpcion($nomMesos); ?>

Comment: Eso ya se adecuaria totalmente a mi problema ahora hare pruebas!

Comment: Ahora ya no molesto más @Guillem pero no se podria hacer todo como esta pero en un unico archivo php?

Comment: @InfoTipsconJavitoBCN ya tienes las modificaciones y alguna anotación en la respuesta principal, espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: @Guillem estoy en el chat . Okay!

Comment: @Guillem tengo una duda en un ejercicio PHP mañana estarás por aquí?

Comment: @InfoTipsconJavitoBCN estoy por aquí

Comment: Ara estas? @Guillem?

Comment: @InfoTipsconJavitoBCN si

Comment: @Guillem vale pos entra al chat porfa que ja estic per qui